# How should I refactor this Haskell code to make it more elegant?

Tags: string, haskell

As an exercise I wrote a short Haskell function that returns the first four characters of a string, concatenated. I had great trouble converting the chars to strings and resorted to an ugly `replicate` hack.  What's the best way to improve this function? (I'm guessing that both the pattern and the output can be improved.)

```
concatFirstFour :: [Char] -> [Char]
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = (replicate 1 a) ++ (replicate 1 b) ++ (replicate 1 c) ++ (replicate 1 d)
concatFirstFour xs = error "Need at least four characters."
```

**Update:** Thank you so much, everyone. I learned several things from all the answers and comments.  I understand types much better.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
initFirstFour :: [a] -> [a]
initFirstFour str 
               | length str > 3 = take 4 str
               | otherwise      = error "Need at least four characters."
```

**Update 2:** Changed the second pattern from xs to _ per ptival's comment. Lazy eval FTW.

**Update 3:** Cleaner guards from tew88's comment.

Comment: `concatFirstFour :: [a] -> [a]` is better

Comment: Note that you do not need to name `xs` in the last line of your code, since the argument is never used in the function body. You can replace it with the wilcard `_`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = [a,b,c,d]
concatFirstFour _           = error "Need at least four characters."
```

or

```
concatFirstFour = take 4
```

but this last one doesn't fail on short lists...

---

Also note you don't need to specify the type is a [Char] (or String), since you never use this assumption in the code. Let it be [a] -> [a].

Answer (score 4):

Strings are just lists of characters, so you don't need to convert characters to string and then concatenate the strings. There are a few different ways to do this.

First off, if you want a list with just one element, you can use `[x]`. So:

```
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = [a] ++ [b] ++ [c] ++ [d]
```

But this isn't really necessary. You could just do this:

```
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = [a, b, c, d]
```

Or this:

```
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = a:b:c:d:[]
```

Or, my preferred way:

```
concatFirstFour str = take 4 str
```

Since `str` is just a list, you can `take` the first four characters to get a new "string."

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using the 'otherwise' keyword as part of your guard expression:

```
initFirstFour :: [a] -> [a]
initFirstFour xs
    | length xs > 3 = take 4 xs
    | otherwise     = error "Need at least four characters."
```

I think this is a bit more readable (and elegant) than your chosen method of pattern matching.

Comment: This fails on infinite lists, unlike the rest of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Ptival's solution using pattern matching. But this one doesn't error with strings less than 4 chars.

```
concatFirstFour (a:b:c:d:_) = [a,b,c,d]
concatFirstFour xs       = xs
```